# Почему не верно срабатывает проверка на тип данных?

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunc(myNumber) {
    if (typeof Number != myNumber){
        alert("Вы передали не Number");
        return myNumber
    }
    else{
        return 10 + myNumber;
    }
}

var myNumber = 10;
myNumber = myFunc(myNumber);
console.log(myNumber);
```

Comment: `if (typeof myNumber === "number")`

Comment: `return 10 + myNumber;` - тут вы строку получите, кстати.

Comment: Почему бы не почитать синтаксис по [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)? Сразу поймёте ошибку.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в консоли в итоге было 20, а если человек вводит не число то ошибка.

Если я возьму number в кавычки это не решает проблему

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала давайте разберемся с тем, что конструкторы стандартных типов не являются этими самыми типами как в других языках. Они все являются функциями-прототипами. И уже в свою очередь возвращают нужный объект.

Поскольку они все являются функциями, то сравнивать их по типу с чем-то кроме функций бессмысленно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам правильно сказали почитать документацию по typeof, это ключевое слово возвращает строку с названием типа. Поэтому даже если бы Number был числом, то получили бы в итоге строку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сравнение строки с числом тоже ничего нормального не даст. Правильный вариант перевести само число в тип и сравнить.

```
"number" != typeof myNumber
```

Ну и полный код

```js
function myFunc(myNumber) {
    if ("number" != typeof myNumber){
        alert("Вы передали не Number");
        return myNumber
    }
    else{
        return 10 + myNumber;
    }
}

var myNumber = 10;
myNumber = myFunc(myNumber);
console.log(myNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы сравниваете

```
typeof Number != myNumber
```

Вы сравниваете функцию (typeof Number) с числом. 
Как написали выше, вам нужно определить тип переменной.

```
function myFunc(myNumber) {
  console.log(typeof myNumber);
    if (typeof myNumber !== "number"){
        alert("Вы передали не Number");
        return myNumber;
    }
    else{
        return 10 + myNumber;
    }
}

var myNumber = 10;
myNumber = myFunc(myNumber);
console.log(myNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильный синтаксис будет:  `typeof (myNumber) != "number"`

```
function myFunc(myNumber) {
    if (typeof (myNumber) != "number"){
        alert("Вы передали не Number");
        return myNumber;
    }
    else{
        return 10 + myNumber;
    }
}

var myNumber = 10;
myNumber = myFunc(myNumber);
console.log(myNumber);
```

Оператор **typeof** возвращает тип аргумента.

У него есть два синтаксиса: со скобками и без:

1. Синтаксис оператора: typeof x.
2. Синтаксис функции: typeof(x).

https://learn.javascript.ru/types-intro#type-typeof